# UITextView places text lower than I want it to be

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitextview

I got UITextView with some text. Text always appears not in the upper left corner of the text view but with a large indent from upper border like this:
[textView with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1CB5.jpg)

I set attribute "content mode" to "Top left" like this but it did not helped:
[attribute setted to top left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maYfr.jpg)

Method `[self.infoTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];` didn't helped.
Method `[self.infoTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];` can do the job BUT it moves text only if it is already visible to user so it creates a mess in a UI (First user sees text at the bottom and then text instantly changes position).

How do i place a text in the top left corner of UITextView before it appears on screen? Will appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

BTW I am using Xcode version 8.2.1.

Comment: You are using `UIEdgeInsetsMake ` somewhere. Check your project again.

Comment: @agent_stack No, I am not using this function, search in project did not find anything on it. Also I tried `self.infoTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 0, 0);` but it works only on already visible text view as well other methods I tried.

Comment: What actually you wants? Yeah, this edgeInset set the text inside the textView.

Comment: @agent_stack I want the text inside the textView already be in the top left corner in the moment text view appears on screen. But all the methods I try, they actually move already visible text in the corner and user sees this text relocation from first position to second. And this looks like awful UI.

Comment: Whenever you add a `textView` by default its text is aligned from the top-left. Add what you have done regarding to the `textView` so that can figure out whats wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I added fresh new `textView` and it's content was exactly in the top left corner. I am sure that i did nothing with `textView` in my code and in storyboard file. I saw this bug in more than one of my projects but previous time adding fresh new `textView` did not solve the problem. This time - it helped. Thanks for your answers!